# Why does adding a string to a dict split the string into individual characters?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a dict with 2 keys: artists and songs
and I have to put the values on it

```
def dict_musics(): 
    r = (get_songs.json()['toptracks']['track'])
    artists = {'artists': [], 'songs': []}
    for i in range(3):
        artists['artists'] += r[i]['artist']['name']
        artists['songs'] += r[i]['name']
    return artists

print(dict_musics())
```

my output:

```
{'artist': ['H', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'y', ' ', 'S', 't', 'y', 'l', 'e', 's', 'S', 'i', 'm', 'M', 'å', 'n', 'e', 's', 'k', 'i', 'n'], 'song': ['A', 's', ' ', 'I', 't', ' ', 'W', 'a', 's', 'T', 'h', 'e', ' ', 'R', 'u', 'm', 'b', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '(', 'T', 'V', ' ', 'S', 'i', 'z', 'e', ')', 'V', 'E', 'N', 'T', "'", 'A', 'N', 'N', 'I']}
```

expected:

```
{'artist': ['Harry Styles', 'Sim', 'Maneskin], 'song': ['As It Was', 'The Rumbling (TV Size)', 'VENT'ANNI']}
```

whats wrong?

Comment: 1. You need to provide a [mre]. We can't reproduce your problem because we have no idea what `get_songs.json()` returns. 2. Don't spam irrelevant tags. Your question has nothing to do with [tag:dictionary] or [tag:key-value-store]

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a += "hello"
>>> a
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Thus, `+=` does *not* append to the list, which is what you're looking for:

```
artists['artists'].append(r[i]['artist']['name'])
```

Instead, you're `extend`ing the list:

```
artists['artists'].extend(r[i]['artist']['name'])
```